# Can't return boolean using "return of(false)"

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

My aim is to load in some data, store it and return *true* or *false* to the requesting method. My idea was to perform the operation and then go *return of(true)* creating an observable. I have the following method.

```
setValidations(): Observable<boolean> {
  ...
  this.http.get<Validation[]>(url)
    .subscribe(
      suc => {
        environment.validations = suc;
        return of(true);
      },
      err => of(false)
    );
}
```

The computer complains that I need to return something of type *Observable*, so I'm concluding that I failed on the syntax. How do I fix it?

**edit according to answers/comments**

```
setValidations(): Observable<boolean> {
  ...
  return this.http.get<Validation[]>(url)
    .pipe(
      map(_ => { console.log("success"); return of(true); }),
      catchError => { console.log("success"); return of(false); }
    );
}
```

I changed the method as shown above. It seems to work but produces a warning about a shadowed variable called *catchError*. Bit worried that I'm doing something less good here.

Comment: You don't subscribe. You return an observable created from the original http one, by applying operators (like map), on it. https://angular.io/guide/rx-library

Comment: @JBNizet I fail to see how I'm supposed to use pipe and map to return a new observable of type boolean. I have used pipe and map before but get stuck on the specifics here. Care to post a short sample?

Comment: `pipe(tap(suc => environment.validations = suc), map(() => true), catchError(() => of(false)))`

Comment: This was interesting. Undeniably, it works. I have two follow-ups though. (1) Why *tap* instead of using *map* with a body and store the stuff, then returning *true*? Is it for lowering the complexity of each line? (2) It confuses me why we return a fixed value in *map* but return an observable value in *catchError*. It seems inconsistent that the former gets observable'ized somehow while the latter doesn't.

Comment: map vs catchError: see the reference documentation. tap + map vs map only: because tap is for side effects, and map is for transforming events, so I find it clearer to be explicit about having a side-effect by using tap instead of hiding the side-effect in map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `error` is a `void` callback; you can't return from there, no chance. Semantically, at the very moment you've gotten there, you're screwed; by definition, `rxjs` is `next*(complete|error)`-like stream of events, so as soon as first (actually, **single**) error seen, it kind of breaks down. To handle possible error and keep your intance alive, you have to `pipe` your original `Observer` through the `catchError` operator ([docs & examples are here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html)).

```
setValidations(): Observable<boolean> {
  ...
  return this.http.get<Validation[]>(url)
    .pipe(
      tap(suc => environment.validations = suc),
      map(() => true),
      catchError(() => of(false))
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I updated the question with the code altered according to your suggestion. Is that what you meant? Why do I get the warning?

Comment: @KonradViltersten except that you don't have to `map` to `of(false)`. Take some time to walk through the docs, otherwise `rxjs` will resist you all day long.

Comment: I took the liberty to update your answer for future, lazy visitors. It raises a question, though. It confuses me why I'm supposed to return a simple, boolean *true* in *map* while I have to create an observable for *false. Seems so inconsequential.

Comment: Catch error needs to returns an observable. So instead of returning the error observable, you are returning the boolean `false` value instead